# Drawing shapes on canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

I have some problem. I would like to create applications paint which enabling them to draw different shapes. He wants to use the strategy pattern to change the tool used to draw. Unfortunately, I do not know how to keep the drawn shapes to be the ability to undo and change the color of specific shapes by clicking on them.

Comment: wait... what?? Please rephrase your question, I have NO idea what you question is. Who is `He`, and WHY he wanted to use strategy-pattern? What you want to archive? What have you tried? Did you read the faq? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have a problem with the storage of what I drew. I would like to be able to undo the changes. Currently, each shape is treated as a bitmap, but this is not an efficient solution.